# Find the name of a File run by a .jar file

Tags: java, file, jar

I built a .jar file, ex. Test.jar. I open pictures in my computer by this Test.jar file.

How can I receive the absolute path of this picture?

```
package Run;

import Controll.Controller;
import View.MainFrame;


public class Run {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MainFrame view = new MainFrame();
        Controller controller = new Controller(view, fileName);        
    }       

}
```

I write my project by MVC (Model - View - Control) model. The MainFrame class is the view, where i display the picture. The Controller class is the Control where control all works of my project, the constructor of Controller receive twos parameter, one is the View, and another is the fileName (name of the picture that i open by this .jar file). After receiving 2 these parameters, the Controller will display the picture in the View (a Frame).

It means, how can I receive the fileName in the Run.class to pass the parameter fileName into the Controller to work with this file?

Comment: how about you showing your code for files available in this jar

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want to do, but see if this helps: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()

Comment: what is the question?  are you looking for _JFileChooser.getSelectedFiles()_

Comment: Sorry about my question :(, i edited it :(

Comment: What is a `Controller`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"i edited it"*  +1  *"Sorry about my question"*  No need for apologies, an edit is always better. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson An sscce is great; but I did not think knowing what a `Controller` is is relevant to this question.

Comment: @Shobit If it was not relevant to the SSCCE, it would not be in it. +1 for you answer.

Comment: Right, but the only thing that was relevant to the question was knowing that there's a `Controller` somewhere that needs a fileName. What I meant was that I did not need to know what a `Controller` is exactly. Thanks for the +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the filename as an argument. It will be received in the `args[]` array in the `main` method.

So if you do `java Run "/home/something/filename.jpg"`

you can access it in the main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String fileName = args[0];
}
```

Comment: If I put my Run.jar file in the location: C:\\Test1\\run.jar. And I open a picture in another place (like C:\\Test2\pic.jpg) with this .jar file. Will it pass the C:\\Test2\\pic.jpg into args[0] ?

Comment: You could send (as command line argument) with single backslashes, i.e., no need to escape them. e.g. C:\Users\foo\baz.jpg

Comment: Yes, it passes as argument whatever you send through the command-line, as is. So you can run your jar from anyplace and provide absolute path names for the picture files. java -jar Run.jar "C:\Users\foo\baz.jpg"